# how to submit form when the flip switcher go to on state in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-mobile, setinterval, jquery-mobile-flipswitch

I have simple form contain two input user name & password and flip swithcher I  want to sumbitt the form when the flip go to on state I try using this :

```
<select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
<option value="off"></option>
<option value="on"><input type="submit" value="" data-inline="true" /></option>
            </select>
```

but not work any one can help???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a working code.

**HTML :**

```
<form id="some-form">
    <select name="flip-1" id="flip-1" data-role="slider">
        <option value="off"></option>
        <option value="on">Submit</option>
    </select>                                
</form>
```

**Javascript :**

```
$(document).on('change', '#flip-1', function(){    
    if($("#flip-1 option:selected").attr('value') == 'on') {
        $('#some-form').submit();
    }
});
```

**EDIT :**

This should do it:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){       
    $(document).on('change', '#flip-1', function(){    
        if($("#flip-1 option:selected").attr('value') == 'on') {
            $('#some-form').submit();
            var timer = setInterval(function() { 
                $('#flip-1 option[value="off"]').attr('selected','selected');
                $('#flip-1').slider('refresh'); 
                clearInterval(timer);
            }, 500)
        }
    });
});
```

setInterval is here just so it can look like flip switch was turned on then off.

Comment: dear can I aske: How to retrn to off status after sbmitt?? thx in advance :)

Comment: So you want to reset switch to off after the submit?

Comment: dear can you solve this Q: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415005/refresh-jquery-mobile-page-after-load?noredirect=1#comment23537619_16415005]