# refresh jquery mobile page after load

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, iscroll, jquery-mobile-ajax

I have two pages, A and B:

A --> login page.

B --> contain HTML elements and iScoll "pull to refreash" code.

evrey thing works fine but when I login from A to B the iScroll content Not appear, if i do refresh for page B the content appear back and work well, this is iScroll code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var myScroll,
    pullDownEl, pullDownOffset,
    generatedCount = 0;

    function pullDownAction() {
        setTimeout(function () {    
            var el, li, i;
            el = document.getElementById('thelist');

            var returnedLIs = "";
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                returnedLIs += '<li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" class="PDFLink"></a></li>';

            }
            $(returnedLIs).prependTo($('#thelist'));
            myScroll.refresh(); 
        }, 0); 
    }


    function loaded() {
        pullDownEl = document.getElementById('pullDown');
        pullDownOffset = pullDownEl.offsetHeight;

        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
            hideScrollbar:false,
            useTransition: true,
            topOffset: pullDownOffset,
            onRefresh: function () {
                if (pullDownEl.className.match('loading')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                } 

            },
            onScrollMove: function () {
                if (this.y > 5 && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = 'flip';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                    this.minScrollY = 0;
                } else if (this.y < 5 && pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                    this.minScrollY = -pullDownOffset;
                } 
                                },
            onScrollEnd: function () {
                if (pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = 'loading';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                    pullDownAction(); // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
                } 

            }
        });

        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '0'; }, 800);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);


</script>
```

can any one help,,,

**edit**: `<head>` section for A.aspx --> Login page:

```
<head runat="server">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
    <link href="css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- Validition Library -->
    <script src="Validate/jquery.validVal-4.3.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
```

**edit**: `<head>` section for B.aspx:

```
<head runat="server">

    <%--PULL TO REFREASH--%>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <%--PULL TO REFREASH--%>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>

    <%--PULL TO REFREASH--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jq/iscroll.js"></script>
    <%--PULL TO REFREASH--%>

    <link href="css/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<%--pull to refresh--%>

<script type="text/javascript">



    var myScroll,
    pullDownEl, pullDownOffset,
    generatedCount = 0;

    function pullDownAction() {
        setTimeout(function () {    
            var el, li, i;
            el = document.getElementById('thelist');

            var returnedLIs = "";
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {

                returnedLIs += '<li><a href="#" data-ajax="false" class="PDFLink"></a></li>';

            }
            $(returnedLIs).prependTo($('#thelist'));
            myScroll.refresh(); 
        }, 0);    
    }


    function loaded() {
        pullDownEl = document.getElementById('pullDown');
        pullDownOffset = pullDownEl.offsetHeight;

        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper', {
            hideScrollbar:false,
            useTransition: true,
            topOffset: pullDownOffset,
            onRefresh: function () {
                if (pullDownEl.className.match('loading')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                } 

            },
            onScrollMove: function () {
                if (this.y > 5 && !pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = 'flip';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Release to refresh...';
                    this.minScrollY = 0;
                } else if (this.y < 5 && pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = '';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Pull down to refresh...';
                    this.minScrollY = -pullDownOffset;
                } 

            },
            onScrollEnd: function () {
                if (pullDownEl.className.match('flip')) {
                    pullDownEl.className = 'loading';
                    pullDownEl.querySelector('.pullDownLabel').innerHTML = 'Loading...';
                    pullDownAction(); // Execute custom function (ajax call?)
                } 
            }
        });

        setTimeout(function () { document.getElementById('wrapper').style.left = '0'; }, 800);
    }

    document.addEventListener('touchmove', function (e) { e.preventDefault(); }, false);
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () { setTimeout(loaded, 200); }, false);


</script>
<%--pull to refresh--%>
</head>
```

Comment: `$('[data-role=listview]').listview('refresh')` after you append items to it.

Comment: it should go after this `$(returnedLIs).prependTo($('#thelist'));`, try `$('#thelist').listview('refresh')`.

Comment: yes I do this but still not work ,,,

Comment: try this then `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () {
  $(this).trigger('pagecreate');
 });`

Comment: I add this line 
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () { $(this).trigger('pagecreate'); });

at the beginning of <script> but not work

Comment: Yes, outside the functions you have, you can put it inside `<body>`.

Comment: add this also:
<body>
<script>
    $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () { $(this).trigger('pagecreate'); });

</script> but not work

Comment: Nothing happened? can you post `<head>` links?

Comment: okay I will edit the Q

Comment: Are you using multipages template (one page) or multi-html files? a.html b.html?

Comment: two separate pages, a.aspx, b.aspx

Comment: Do you have same javascript code in both of your html files? And if answer is yes is it placed in HEAD in both cases?

Comment: @Gajotres No they are different I will edit the Q and add the header for the first page

Comment: My point is is your second HTML has its own logic/javascript in its HEAD?

Comment: @Gajotres yes you can see the code in the Q ,I edit it

Comment: then add this `$('#thelist').listview('refresh')` in the second page where you have the `listview` items. you can use it with this `$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '[data-role=page]', function () { $('#thelist').listview('refresh') }); `. let me know what you get.

Comment: @Omar thx but still not work ,,, now I try to refresh the second page by code when it load after login

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain you what is happening.

You have 2 separate HTML pages. Every page has a HEAD with javascript content.

Your problems comes to how jQuery Mobile handles page loading. Only first page is fully loaded. When next page is about to be loaded ONLY its body is loaded into the DOM and rest is discarded. This is because first page is already inside the DOM, there's no point in having to HEAD's inside.

This can be fixed in few ways:

- Move your second page javascript to the HEAD of your first page
- Move your second page javascript to the second page BODY
- When making page transition add these attributes into your link: **data-ajax="false"** or **rel="external"**. Just be waned, in this case transitions wont work so stick to solution 1. or 2.

Also take a look, I have another great answer regarding this + examples: **[Why I have to put all the script to index.html in jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15806954/1848600)**